# How can I return the subarrays in my max k-subarray sum code?

Tags: python, algorithm

Consider an array A of integers of length n.  The k-max subarray sum asks us to find up to k (contiguous) non overlapping subarrays of A with maximum sum.  If A is all negative then this sum will be 0. If A = [-1, 2, -1, 2, -1, 2, 2] for example, then the two subarrays could be [2, -1, 2] and [2, 2] with total sum 7.

The following code is my extension of [Kadane's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem) and runs in O(nk) time, which might be optimal.

```
def solve_SO(test_seq, k=2):
    """
    Computes the k max subarray sum
    """
    num_intervals = k * 2 + 1
    t = None
    best = np.zeros(num_intervals, dtype=int)
    for seq_idx, val in enumerate(test_seq):
        # Add the current value to all the "include" interval best scores
        for interval_idx in range(1, num_intervals, 2):
            best[interval_idx] += val
        # Go over all intervals from the first include one.
        # If we were better off without, update the best score to be the best
        # from the previous interval. This makes best monotonic.
        # The final value is the current best score overall
        for interval_idx in range(1, num_intervals):
            if best[interval_idx] < best[interval_idx - 1]:
                best[interval_idx] = best[interval_idx - 1]
    return best[num_intervals - 1]
```

We can test it with:

```
solve_SO([-1, 2, -1, 2, -1], 2)
Out[22]: 4

In [23]: solve_SO([-1, 2, -1, 2, -1], 1)
Out[23]: 3
```

I can't work out how to return the subarrays that are being used to form the final sum.  In the first case I would like to output `[(1, 2), (3, 4]]` and in the second case `[(1, 4)]` to show the subarrays as interval pairs in the original array.

I realise that this should be doable by storing something after:

```
            if best[interval_idx] < best[interval_idx - 1]:
                best[interval_idx] = best[interval_idx - 1]
```

but I can't work out how to do it correctly.

How can my code be modified to do that?

Comment: Maybe you could use a list instead of the sum value. Then when comparing, you can use the sum of list items, and return the resulting list.

Comment: @ftorre If  you could show me how to get that to work that would be great.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to actually generate the best subarrays, the usual procedure is to keep track of the predecessors of every state.

When you get to the end, start with the best state, and backtrack through the predecessor links to find the sequence of operations that generated it:

```python
def solve_SO(test_seq, k=2):
    """
    Computes the k max subarray sum
    """
    num_intervals = k * 2 + 1
    t = None
    best = np.zeros(num_intervals, dtype=int)
    preds = np.zeros([len(test_seq),num_intervals], dtype=np.int8)

    for seq_idx, val in enumerate(test_seq):
        # Add the current value to all the "include" interval best scores
        for interval_idx in range(1, num_intervals, 2):
            best[interval_idx] += val
        # Go over all intervals from the first include one.
        # If we were better off without, update the best score to be the best
        # from the previous interval. This makes best monotonic.
        # The final value is the current best score overall
        for interval_idx in range(1, num_intervals):
            if best[interval_idx] < best[interval_idx - 1]:
                best[interval_idx] = best[interval_idx - 1]
                preds[seq_idx][interval_idx] = 1
            else:
                preds[seq_idx][interval_idx] = 0
    
    # calculate the best number of subarrays
    current_interval = 0
    for interval_idx in range(0,num_intervals,2):
        if best[interval_idx] > best[current_interval]:
            current_interval = interval_idx

    #b Backtrack through the predecessor path to generate the optimal arrays
    ret = []
    open_end = 0
    for seq_idx in range(len(test_seq)-1, -1, -1):
        if preds[seq_idx][current_interval]:
            # best result opened or closed a subarray here
            if current_interval%2:
                # started a new array after this index
                ret.append((seq_idx+1, open_end))
            else:
                # last index in subarray
                open_end = seq_idx+1
            current_interval -= 1
    if current_interval:
        # index 0 is in the first subarray
        ret.append((0,open_end))
        
    ret.reverse()
    return ret
```

Comment: This is great, thank you. I was really hoping there was a simpler/shorter solution by keeping track of the optimal intervals but maybe there isn't.

Comment: You can do it by keeping track of all the subarrays for each state, too.  That's not faster, but it takes O(k^2) space instead of O(kn) space, albeit with a larger constant factor.